# styles called with wp_enqueue fires, but not scripts

Tags: wordpress, function, wordpress-theming

I am trying to use wp_enqueue approach insted of hard coding styles and scripts in my wordpress site. I came across a probme where my stylesheets enqueued with 'wp_enqueue_style' works but my scripts enqueued with wp_enqueue_script does not.

It is a standalone theme. As of my code below, why are the styles imported but not the scripts? Thanks!

```
//functions.php
    <?php
    // hook
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'souteEast_load' );
    // Register some javascript & css files
    function souteEast_load() {
        // Styles ------>
      wp_enqueue_style( 'Material+Icons', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons' , false, NULL, 'all' );
      wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery.bxslider.css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/jquery.bxslider/jquery.bxslider.css', false, NULL, 'all');
      wp_enqueue_style( 'materialize.css', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/materialize/css/materialize.min.css',  false, NULL, 'all');
      wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_template_directory_uri().'/css/style.css',  false, NULL, 'all');
      // Scripts ------>
      //wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery-1.12.4', 'https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js', array(), null, true );
      wp_enqueue_script( 'materialize.js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/materialize/js/materialize.min.js', array("jquery"), null, true );
      wp_enqueue_script( 'google-maps', 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCC7iX9atpPZKCo2pnbCDXVXQjaukKs_60', array("jquery"), null, true );
      wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.bxslider.js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/jquery.bxslider/jquery.bxslider.min.js', array("jquery"), null, true );
      wp_enqueue_script( 'main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array("jquery"), null, true );
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to add `<?php wp_footer(); ?>` in the footer, therefore adding "true" in the in_footer argument would make wordpress not loading the files because i had no footer.. Feel so stupid.